# C++ - Convert array of floats to std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

I have an array of floats with a fixed length. Now I want to convert that array to a binary string.

I cannot use `const char *` because my string will contain null-bytes. How would I use memcpy in that case? I have already tried a `reinterpret_cast<string *>`, but that won't work because the string is also/only storing pointers to the begin and end of the data (correct me if I am wrong).

I'm already constructing an empty string:

```
string s;
s.resize(arr_size);
```

But how would I copy an array of floats to that string?

**Basically, I want to dump the memory region of a fixed float array to a string.**

Don't be to hard with me, I'm still learning c++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

float data[10]; // populate

std::string s(sizeof data);
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(data);

std::copy(p, p + sizeof data, &s[0]);
```

Note that `sizeof data` is the same as `10 * sizeof(float)`, i.e. the number of bytes in the array.

*Update:* As suggested by James, you can do even better and write it all in one go:

```
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(data);
std::string s(p, p + sizeof data);  // beginning + length constructor
```

Or even:

```
#include <iterator>

std::string s(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(std::begin(data)),  // begin + end
              reinterpret_cast<char const *>(std::end(data)));   // constructor
```

Comment: If you use the two iterator constructor of string, you don't have to worry about the size.

Comment: I'm getting `warning C4996` (but I think it's ok) .. but I'm also getting `error C3892 - you cannot assign to a variable that is const` .. might that be because s.data() is const?

Comment: @H2CO3 How's that?  Either you are calling it with the definition of the array, in which case, you use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` (or the equivalents in your tool kit in pre-C++11), or you're in a function which has been passed a pointer, in which case, the function also takes either a length (in elements) or an end pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze Disregard... Forgot about `std::begin()` and `std::end()`... Sorry.

Comment: and how do you print this using printf?

Comment: Even simpler, `std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), sizeof(data))`. No need to use beginning and end pointers. Just tell it how long the array is in bytes.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that this is technically UB - shouldn't we be using memcpy here rather than std::copy?

Comment: @RichardHodges: No, why? We're operating on chars, which have express license to alias and to communicate object representations. And a good library implementation would use `memcpy` for this anyway: https://godbolt.org/z/Nyhvn6

Answer (score 4):

Getting all of the bytes of the array into a string is easy:

```
std::string
bitwiseDump( float const* begin, float const* end )
{
    return std::string( reinterpret_cast<char const*>( begin ),
                        reinterpret_cast<char const*>( end ) );
}
```

But why?  There's nothing you can do with the string except copy
it back into an array of the same type.  (And even for that use,
`std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` would be
more natural.  And less obfuscating.)

Comment: I'm using a graphics engine which needs the vertex data as a binary string :)

Comment: This should be a template :-)

Comment: You mean it takes an `std::string` with the binary data as a parameter?  That's a very poorly designed interface.

Comment: @KerrekSB I more or less agree, and I started to write it as such.  On the other hand, it's easy to convert into a template if the need arises, and the use is so limited that it almost certainly won't.

Comment: @KerrekSB On the other hand, the template might become interesting if you define the function `std::string bitwiseDump( float (&array)[N} )`, with a template argument `size_t N`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That would be the second overload, which delegates to the first :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes.  Without knowing more about the actual application, it's hard to say what is really needed.  For example, I tend not to use arrays, but `std::vector`, which means that I don't need anything special to get the size or an end iterator.  But I don't know the OP's application domain, nor the library he's interfacing to, so I really cannot say.  (In my application, I have relatively few, long lived arrays, of hundreds of elements, whose size isn't known until run time.  So C style arrays aren't an option, and the cost of dynamic allocation is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string floatString;
    std::array<float, 5> data = {1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f};

    for (auto& element : data)
        floatString.append(std::to_string(element));

    std::cout << floatString;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: My fault, I also didn't read that the OP wants to get it in binary representation...