# C++ - Convert std::string of float array

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

This question is a follow up to [C++ - Convert array of floats to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964859/c-convert-array-of-floats-to-stdstring).

How to convert a `std::string` back to float array that was converted to string using `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the string's backing data pointer from  the `c_str()` method. Then reinterpret_cast it back to the float pointer.

```
const float* array_of_floats = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(str.c_str());
int len = str.size() / sizeof(float);
```

In general, serializing binary data (such as array of floats) into `string` can work, but is at best weird and more likely ill-advised.  You are better off using `std::vector<uint8_t>` as an array of bytes to hold your floating pointer data instead of an instance of a string.

Comment: Getting following error main.cpp:20:16: error: reinterpret_cast from 'const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char *') to 'float *' casts away qualifiers
    float *d = reinterpret_cast<float*>(s.c_str());
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: ahhh… I forgot.  `c_str()` returns a `const char*`.  Therefore, you need to cast to a `const float*`.  Answer updated.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena be advised that the `array_of_floats` pointer is only valid as long as the underlying string exists and is unchanged. It might be better to copy the floats into a separate array instead of relying on a pointer to the string data.

Comment: @john I am planning to store string in db.